# Including mpHealth feature breaks standalone application in Open Liberty

Tags: open-liberty, microprofile

I'm currently playing with Open Liberty 18.0.0.4 and its Microprofile support. When I try to build a standalone runnable Jar which includes the mpHealth-1.0 feature, startup fails with

```
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0033E: The singleton features com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javax.servlet-3.1 and com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javax.servlet-4.0 cannot be loaded at the same time.  The configured features mpHealth-1.0 and jaxrs-2.1 include one or more features that cause the conflict. Your configuration is not supported; update server.xml to remove incompatible features.
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0033E: The singleton features com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javax.annotation-1.2 and com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javax.annotation-1.3 cannot be loaded at the same time.  The configured features mpHealth-1.0 and jaxrs-2.1 include one or more features that cause the conflict. Your configuration is not supported; update server.xml to remove incompatible features.
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0033E: The singleton features com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javaeeCompatible-8.0 and com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javaeeCompatible-7.0 cannot be loaded at the same time.  The configured features jsonb-1.0 and mpHealth-1.0 include one or more features that cause the conflict. Your configuration is not supported; update server.xml to remove incompatible features.
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0033E: The singleton features com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javax.cdi-2.0 and com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javax.cdi-1.2 cannot be loaded at the same time.  The configured features jsonb-1.0 and mpHealth-1.0 include one or more features that cause the conflict. Your configuration is not supported; update server.xml to remove incompatible features.
```

I'm using jaxrs-2.1 and jsonb-1.0 and everything works fine. As soon as I add  the mpHealth-1.0 feature I get the above errors. Here's the relevant snippet of the server.xml:

```
    <featureManager>
        <feature>jaxrs-2.1</feature>
        <feature>jsonb-1.0</feature>
        <feature>mpHealth-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
```

And this is what the started Jar says at then end (but no service will be available):

```
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [jsonb-1.0, servlet-4.0, jndi-1.0, mpHealth-1.0, json-1.0, cdi-1.2, jsonp-1.1, jaxrsClient-2.1, jaxrs-2.1].
```

Comment: can you update your question with the features that you have enabled in server.xml? That will tell us all the features that are in play. Not all OpenLiberty features are compatible with each other, but these features should be.

Comment: I updated my question. Since all those features are part of MicroProfile 2.1 how can it be that they are incompatible? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Are those the only 3 features you have enabled in server.xml?  I just tested out adding these 3 features locally in a server and it worked fine for me. If you include the `<featureManager>` block of server.xml, or the `CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: ...` message in your question, that will help us know for sure what's going on

Comment: I can also provide you the complete projects if that helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because not all OpenLiberty features are compatible with each other, and if you enable conflicting features you get an error indicating which features conflict. It should be resolvable by enabling additional features in your server.xml to help the runtime disambiguate which features should be enabled.

The two main reasons features conflict are:

1. Two versions of the same feature try to be enabled (e.g. `foo-1.0` and `foo-2.0`)
2. A mix of Java EE 7 and Java EE 8 features are enabled (e.g. `cdi-1.2` from EE 7 and `jaxrs-2.1` from EE 8)

To break down the feature dependencies of what you have enabled, it looks something like this:

```
- jsonb-1.0 -> jsonp-1.1
- jaxrs-2.1 -> cdi-2.0
            -> servlet-4.0
- mpHealth-1.0 -> cdi-1.2 (tolerates cdi-2.0)
```

The reason you are seeing these errors is because the OpenLiberty feature manager does not have sufficient evidence to know that it can failover to the `mpHealth-1.0 -> cdi-2.0` dependency.

To fix this, you have two options:

1. Enable the `cdi-2.0` feature in server.xml. This should help to disambiguate for the feature manager so it can failover to the `mpHealth-1.0 -> cdi-2.0` dependency.
2. Instead of enabling individual features, enable the `microProfile-2.0` convenience feature. Here you won't have to worry about feature conflicts, but it will load more features into the runtime (e.g. MP Metrics, MP Config, MP Fault Tolerance, etc), which will incur some additional startup time and memory footprint cost.

Comment: Adding `cdi-2.0` as an explicit feature resolved the problem. Thanks for the quick resolution!

Comment: For me, this problem was triggered when updating from 18.0.0.4 to 18.0.0.8. In 18.0.0.4, it worked without cdi-2.0 reference